# How to change private files root directory in Android

Tags: java, android, file

With private files root directory I mean the one that os returned with getFilesDir().

Problem is that I'd like to create a directory inside that directory and then, for example read a file created there with openFileInput.

But openFileInput only supports a file name, indeed if you try to use a String with / it raises error.

So, is there any way I could chance the directory, so when I pass the file name to it, openFileInput would properly read it?

Comment: No. But whats against FileInput/OutputStream?

Comment: @blackapps, tried it but didn't work, I guess It needs more adaptation, and this didn't seem hard todo if It were posible. As it's not, I'll research more

Comment: I do not see difficulties. Please post your code.